# Fatal error</b>: Call to undefined function

Tags: php

if i have this structure:

```
function one () {
    if (4>3) {
        return true;
    }
    else
    return false;
}

function two () {
    if (one()) {
        echo ("ok");
    }
    else
    echo("first function have a problem");
}
```

this works without any problem.

but now, if i have:

```
class all {
    function one () {
        if (4>3) {
            return true;
        }
        else
        return false;
    }

    public function two () {
        if (one()) {
            echo ("ok");
        }
        else
        echo("first function have a problem");
    }
}

$val = new all();
$val -> two ();
```

i receive: Fatal error:  Call to undefined function  one (); 
Why?

thanks

Answer (score 11):

In PHP, you must explicitly say that you are calling an object's method. In some languages it is implicit; in PHP it is not.

You need to use `$this`:

```
        if ($this->one()) {
```

See [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).  As other answers have said, if you omit `$this` the function call is treated as a call to a global function.

Answer (score 3):

There, won't complain anymore about fatal errrzz:

```
class all {
    function one () {
        if (4>3) {
            return true;
        }
        else
        return false;
    }

    public function two () {
        if ($this->one()) {
            echo ("ok");
        }
        else
        echo("first function have a problem");
    }
}

$val = new all();
$val->two();
```